# Angular (5) input variables seem to be

Tags: angular

I recently updated my Angular project from 4 to 5. I noticed some changes however that I cannot explain.

I have a `ParentComponent` and a `ChildComponent`. `ChildComponent` receives an `InputObject` from the parent.

**Behavior before update:**
If I change something on `InputObject` in my `ParentComponent`, this can be seen in `ChildComponent`.

**Behavior after update:**
If I change something on `InputObject` in my `ParentComponent`, this change does not happen in `ChildComponent`.

Is this correct behavior? If it is, how should multiple components work on a same object?

Comment: I upgraded to Angular 5 aswell, but for me changes on the InputObject in the ParentComponent do affect the ChildComponent.

Comment: can you please add some code you are working

Comment: I'll work on a plunker

Comment: The best way to figure out what's going wrong is to implement OnChange in your child component and console your object in ngOnChange. If change detect by Angular then it obviously you need to  tell angular that I want ChangeDetection in my component. By default the behaviour is default but somehow it changed to OnPush. You need to specify in your childcomponent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the change you are doing involves the update of a specific property it should work, but if you are updating the whole object (e.g. `var obj = anotherObj`) Angular will not trigger the change detection because it doesn't make a deep comparison due to performance.

[Angular Documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges)

> The log entries appear as the string value of the power property changes. But the ngOnChanges does not catch changes to hero.name That's surprising at first.
>   Angular only calls the hook when the value of the input property changes. The value of the hero property is the reference to the hero object. Angular doesn't care that the hero's own name property changed. The hero object reference didn't change so, from Angular's perspective, there is no change to report!

Comment: I don't think it is specific to ng5 ?